# How to maximize my Emacs height on start-up?

Tags: fullscreen

`emacs -fh` would start emacs in window mode using full height available from the desktop environment. I'm tired of typing this `-fh` every time yet there doesn't seem to exist a command that does the same as `-fh`

Answer (score 1):

There are `initial-frame-alist` and `default-frame-alist` variables. Add `fullscreen` parameter with value `fullheight` in one you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you load the library `frame-cmds.el` then you can place the following in your init file:

```
(when (display-graphic-p)
  (add-hook 'window-setup-hook #'maximize-frame-vertically))
```

The conditional is to make sure you are not running in a terminal window, where maximisation would not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen gives a command `toggle-max-frame-vertically` which would only work if you download and install their `frame-cmds.el`.